# What's the difference between "used to" and "would"?

Tags: grammar

I have learned some information about this topic, but still have some not getting things.
The used to construction in English is used to tell about an action that happened or was often repeated in the past, but is no longer happening at the moment.
How should I write this sentence:
-Sometimes we would /used to wake up early in the morning and go on a bike  ride in the woods until nightfall.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! A good question here demonstrates that you've done some research on your own rather then asking others to do it for you. A simple Google search should give you many sites that answer this question clearly. If after doing that research, you're still confused, please show us what you've found and tell us which aspect of it you still need help with, then we're happy to help. [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In this case (describing a habitual action  in the past), you can use either.  When describing a fact or condition that is no longer true (_I used to live in London_ or _I used to have black hair before I went grey_), you can't use _would_.

Comment: I agree with Kate's comment. In addition, **would** is quite formal when used about past habitual actions.

Comment: "not getting things" should be "things that I don't get (informal) /understand (formal)".